# For buttons having menu in toolbar, when click on any one button menu displays on hover for all buttons Ext JS 6.5.3

Tags: extjs6.5

Just copy and run the below code in sencha fiddle link [menu button in toolbar fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2n5i&view/editor)

When I have more than one menu button in the toolbar and click on any one button then menu displays for other buttons on hover for all the buttons. I want menu to be displayed only on click and not on button focus or hover.

```
Ext.application({

name: 'Fiddle',

launch: function() {
    Ext.create({
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: 'vbox',
        padding: 20,
        containsFocus : false,
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '0 0 12 0'
        },

        items: [{
            xtype: 'splitbutton',
            text: 'Split Button',
            // click the "Split Button" text to have the click handled
            // by the configured 'handler' function
            handler: function () {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Split Button', 'Button body clicked');
            },
            // clicking on the menu arrow will show the split button menu
            menu: {
                plain: true,
                items: [{
                    text: 'Split Menu Item #1'
                }, {
                    text: 'Split Menu Item #2'
                }],
                listeners: {
                    click: function (menu, item) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Menu Button', item.text);
                    }
                }
            }
        } ,{

            // clicking anywhere on the button will show its configured menu
            text: 'Button with Menu',
            menu: {
                plain: true,
                items: [{
                    text: 'Menu Item #1'
                }, {
                    text: 'Menu Item #2'
                }],
                // the click event handler for all menu items
                listeners: {
                    click: function (menu, item) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Menu Button', item.text);
                    }
                }
            }

        }]
    });
}

});
```

Comment: The link is not working.

Comment: use this update link no need to change the code in this, use as it is https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2n5i&view/editor